# Process Flow triggered Apex Classes showing up as null

Tags: apex, process-builder, scheduled-apex

I have a rather strange bug that has been showing up repeatedly in my production environment. The client wants to keep records of all automated emails being sent, and at times some exotic mixes of recipients. So each email is sent through apex classes. 
  The problem I am encountering is that, the classes all work during testing, work during debugging sessions, work when activating their triggers on the related salesforce object, and work in both sandbox and production environments. 
  However after some time, now without any changes having been made to the processes, the apex classes are throwing errors in the production environment. This shows that the apex class I wish to fire off is listed as Unknown.

```
DECISION: myPostWaitDecision_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Executed this outcome: 
myPostWaitRule_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Outcome conditions: and
1. {!myVariable_current.Status_Date_Assigned_For_Initial_Review__c} 
(1/23/2018 5:48 PM) Is null false
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

UNKNOWN ACTION: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_SA1
Inputs:
LeadIds = {!myVariable_current.Id} (00Q4100000hU5aVEAS)
```

Is this a common error anyone has run accross?  If so is there any suggestions on how to fix the issue? So far moving the offending classes to a 0 time away trigger has fixed some, and moving the others higher up on the immediate actions has also fixed the issue in some areas.

Comment: Is there any error text provided in this log/error email other than the phrase `UNKNOWN ACTION`?

Comment: Error Occurred: Unsupported action type: null